# Cant Post Json Using HttpClient in C#

Tags: c#, http-post, httpclient

I'm trying to make a simple Http Post request.
querydata variable - is my JSON string

```
            var data = new StringContent(queryData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            data.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var httpResponse = await _client.PostAsync(eventRelatriveUrl, data);
```

This request returned with code 405 - method not allowed.
When I open the httpResponse and to to the request I see that the request is GET - I don't understand why
and my content is null.

I have tried the extension method  PostAsJsonAsync - the same result

Thanks for help

Comment: If the endpoint is a GET then you should be calling GetAsync rather than PostAsync ?

Comment: I don't see any reason how a `PostAsync` results in sending a GET instead

Comment: I dont neither...i can add a printscreen